# One-way ANOVA fails with dataframe having completely unique values in columns

Tags: python, unique, statsmodels, anova

So when I run ANOVA with **statsmodel** , I am unable to reach a conclusive result when the dataframe I sent has any column that has completely distinct values for eg: Region column has West, East, South.

so when we run the ANOVA - one way

```
mod = smf.ols('y~x', data=dfx).fit()
aov_table = sma.stats.anova_lm(mod, typ=1)
```

I get an error `ValueError: shapes (2,3) and (2,) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)` where the following table is printed.

```
   table =     df  sum_sq  mean_sq    F  PR(>F)
    0  0.0     0.0      0.0  0.0     0.0
    1  0.0     0.0      0.0  0.0     0.0, n_rows = 2, test = 'F'
    pr_test = 'PR(>F)', robust = None
```

I am planning to drop those columns that have only unique values. But I wanted to know if theres any reason besides this for the above error.

Adding the dfx, (for the column it failed)

```
     x          y
0    A   5.400412
1    B  -2.919641
2    C  -1.022450
3    D   9.851076
4    E  -0.748245
5    F  -9.003224
6    G   2.018952
7    H   4.205281
8    I  19.259112
9    J  12.923128
10   K  -9.833181
11   L   9.517925
12   M   8.117810
13   N   1.347473
14   O  -1.627433
15   P   0.831698
16   Q  -2.780851
17   R   0.303317
18   S   0.573363
19   T  11.629423
20   U        NaN
21   V        NaN
22   W        NaN
23   x        NaN
24   y        NaN
25   z        NaN
26  a1        NaN
27  a2        NaN
28  a3        NaN
```

Comment: Is dfx small enough to display in your question? If so, please do.

Comment: added above as asked.

Comment: `anova_lm` is objecting to the fact that you are are trying to form a linear model where the row rank of (x,y) is less than the row rank of x.

Comment: could you share some reading material on this, I wasn't aware of this requirement.

Comment: When I learned it, which was decades ago, it was from https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2787405-linear-models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make progress of a kind by dropping the rows with nan's for x-values, as in the first line here.

```
>>> df = df.ix[range(20)]
>>> df
    x          y
0   A   5.400412
1   B  -2.919641
2   C  -1.022450
3   D   9.851076
4   E  -0.748245
5   F  -9.003224
6   G   2.018952
7   H   4.205281
8   I  19.259112
9   J  12.923128
10  K  -9.833181
11  L   9.517925
12  M   8.117810
13  N   1.347473
14  O  -1.627433
15  P   0.831698
16  Q  -2.780851
17  R   0.303317
18  S   0.573363
19  T  11.629423
>>> mod = smf.ols('y~x', data=df).fit()
>>> aov_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(mod)
>>> aov_table
            df        sum_sq    mean_sq    F  PR(>F)
x         19.0  1.010356e+03  53.176656  0.0     NaN
Residual   0.0  8.443431e-28        inf  NaN     NaN
```

Comment: ok so it isnt the unique values that was causing the problem. but the presence of NaN in their corresponding 'y' values.